# Foreign composite key to different tables

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to make a unique composed of the modelId and the Item serial number in MS SQL or Transact SQL and I am not sure how to do this.

```
ALTER TABLE [test].[Inventory] ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_UId_Model_SN]
FOREIGN KEY ([UId]) REFERENCES (Models.ModelId, [Inventory].SerialNum)
```

Comment: But Uid is not composite.  This question is confusing.   You cannot have a key across two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create foreign key relationship across multiple tables. Refer the Foreignkey SQL Server Documentation. However you can create composite foreign key like the below.

```
ALTER TABLE [Inventory] ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_UId_Model_SN] FOREIGN KEY (C1,C2) REFERENCES Models (C1,C2)
ALTER TABLE [Inventory] ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_UId_Model_SN] FOREIGN KEY (C1,C2) REFERENCES Inventory (C1,C2)
```